# Find the longest common starting substring in a set of strings

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, haskell, longest-prefix

This is a challenge to come up with the most elegant JavaScript, Ruby or other solution to a relatively trivial problem.

This problem is a more specific case of the [Longest common substring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem). I need to only find the longest common **starting** substring in an array. This greatly simplifies the problem.

For example, the longest substring in `[interspecies, interstelar, interstate]` is "inters". However, I don't need to find "ific" in `[specifics, terrific]`.

I've solved the problem by quickly coding up a solution in JavaScript as a part of my [answer about shell-like tab-completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837555/ajax-autocomplete-or-autosuggest-with-tab-completion-autofill-similar-to-shell/1897480#1897480) ([test page here](http://mislav.net/scripts/autocomplete.html)). Here is that solution, slightly tweaked:

```
function common_substring(data) {
  var i, ch, memo, idx = 0
  do {
    memo = null
    for (i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
      ch = data[i].charAt(idx)
      if (!ch) break
      if (!memo) memo = ch
      else if (ch != memo) break
    }
  } while (i == data.length && idx < data.length && ++idx)

  return (data[0] || '').slice(0, idx)
}
```

This [code is available in this Gist](http://gist.github.com/257891) along with a similar solution in Ruby. You can clone the gist as a git repo to try it out:

```
$ git clone git://gist.github.com/257891.git substring-challenge
```

I'm not very happy with those solutions. I have a feeling they might be solved with more elegance and less execution complexity—that's why I'm posting this challenge.

I'm going to accept as an answer the solution I find the most elegant or concise. Here is for instance a crazy Ruby hack I come up with—defining the `&` operator on String:

```
# works with Ruby 1.8.7 and above
class String
  def &(other)
    difference = other.to_str.each_char.with_index.find { |ch, idx|
      self[idx].nil? or ch != self[idx].chr
    }
    difference ? self[0, difference.last] : self
  end
end

class Array
  def common_substring
    self.inject(nil) { |memo, str| memo.nil? ? str : memo & str }.to_s
  end
end
```

Solutions in JavaScript or Ruby are preferred, but you can show off clever solution in other languages as long as you explain what's going on. Only code from standard library please.

#### Update: my favorite solutions

I've chosen the [JavaScript sorting solution](/questions/1916218/find-the-longest-common-starting-substring-in-a-set-of-strings/1917041#1917041) by [kennebec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80860/kennebec) as the "answer" because it struck me as both unexpected and genius. If we disregard the complexity of actual sorting (let's imagine it's infinitely optimized by the language implementation), the complexity of the solution is just comparing two strings.

Other great solutions:

- ["regex greed"](/questions/1916218/find-the-longest-common-starting-substring-in-a-set-of-strings/1922153#1922153) by FM takes a minute or two to grasp, but then the elegance of it hits you. Yehuda Katz also made [a regex solution](/questions/1916218/find-the-longest-common-starting-substring-in-a-set-of-strings/1916398#1916398), but it's more complex
- [`commonprefix` in Python](/questions/1916218/find-the-longest-common-starting-substring-in-a-set-of-strings/1916632#1916632) — Roberto Bonvallet used a feature made for handling filesystem paths to solve this problem
- [Haskell one-liner](/questions/1916218/find-the-longest-common-starting-substring-in-a-set-of-strings/1918438#1918438) is short as if it were compressed, and beautiful
- [the straightforward Ruby one-liner](/questions/1916218/find-the-longest-common-starting-substring-in-a-set-of-strings/1916480#1916480)

Thanks for participating! As you can see from the comments, I learned a lot (even about Ruby).

Comment: The accepted answer demonstrates a really cool solution. Well, of course, the answer itself is broken, but who cares, the idea is so cool ;)

Comment: Check here for [Analysis of Longest common substring matching](http://www.msccomputerscience.com/2014/10/analysis-of-longest-common-substring_18.html)

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is about code golfing and/or code review, not a discrete programming problem.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It's a matter of taste, but this is a simple javascript version:
It sorts the array, and then looks just at the first and last items.

//longest common starting substring in an array

```
function sharedStart(array){
    var A= array.concat().sort(), 
    a1= A[0], a2= A[A.length-1], L= a1.length, i= 0;
    while(i<L && a1.charAt(i)=== a2.charAt(i)) i++;
    return a1.substring(0, i);
}
```

**DEMOS**

```
sharedStart(['interspecies', 'interstelar', 'interstate'])  //=> 'inters'
sharedStart(['throne', 'throne'])                           //=> 'throne'
sharedStart(['throne', 'dungeon'])                          //=> ''
sharedStart(['cheese'])                                     //=> 'cheese'
sharedStart([])                                             //=> ''
sharedStart(['prefix', 'suffix'])                           //=> ''
```

Comment: I had another thought, if you enter a one element array, the return should logically be the whole string- it does match itself. 
Edited in place, replaced tem1=A.shift() with tem1=A[0].

Comment: Note that sorting is done in O(n·log n).

Comment: You don't have to sort it. Right? Just find the smallest one and the largest one and compare the two.

Comment: This doesn't work if the array has one item or is all duplicates.

Comment: @JeffMay it does now.

Answer (score 38):

In Python:

```
>>> from os.path import commonprefix
>>> commonprefix('interspecies interstelar interstate'.split())
'inters'
```

Comment: Can't believe it. Python has this in stdlib?

Comment: Yes, but it's hidden in the `os.path` module, although it is a string manipulation function useful.

Comment: Good job, python. Feels like cheating.

Answer (score 9):

Ruby one-liner:

```
l=strings.inject{|l,s| l=l.chop while l!=s[0...l.length];l}
```

Comment: This traverses each string once for each character not in the result.  Not very efficient.

Comment: It might need more iterations than other solutions, but I like it. It's what I consider elegant.

Answer (score 9):

You just need to traverse all strings until they differ, then take the substring up to this point.

Pseudocode:

```
loop for i upfrom 0
     while all strings[i] are equal
     finally return substring[0..i]
```

Common Lisp:

```lisp
(defun longest-common-starting-substring (&rest strings)
  (loop for i from 0 below (apply #'min (mapcar #'length strings))
     while (apply #'char=
                  (mapcar (lambda (string) (aref string i))
                          strings))
     finally (return (subseq (first strings) 0 i))))
```

Comment: Isn't it more optimal to do a first pass to find the minmax of available options, in order to reduce the search tree?

Comment: @Denis: 1. There is no "more optimal".  The optimum is the optimum.  There are two optimizations possible in the given Lisp implementation: replace both `apply` forms with `loop`s or `do`s (also eliminating the `mapcar`), and break off in the second one as soon as a mismatch occurs.  2. What is the "minmax of available options" here? 3. There is no search tree here.  If the length of the correct result is _n_, you need to have looked at each character before index _n_ in each input substring.  That is what this routine does, and it looks at each character exactly once, linearly.

Answer (score 9):

My Haskell one-liner:

```
import Data.List

commonPre :: [String] -> String
commonPre = map head . takeWhile (\(x:xs)-> all (==x) xs) . transpose
```

EDIT: barkmadley gave a good explanation of the code below. I'd also add that haskell uses lazy evaluation, so we can be lazy about our use of `transpose`; it will only transpose our lists as far as necessary to find the end of the common prefix.

Comment: This looks like very nice code! Can you take a moment to explain it a bit to us who don't know the language? (You don't have to go to large depths)

Comment: first you transpose the strings.  `["abc","abd","aed"] -> ["aaa","bbe","cdd"]`, then you take from this list until something differs `["aaa"]` and then you take the first element of each list in this list (strings are just lists in Haskell) which gets you `"a"`.  it's easier to read from right to left, because that is the way that data travels in Haskell's point free style.

Comment: Lovely code, but unfortunately this fails when a string is a prefix of another, e.g. `commonPre ["foo", "foobar", "foobarbaz"] == "foobarbaz"`.

Answer (score 6):

Yet another way to do it: use regex greed.

```
words = %w(interspecies interstelar interstate)
j = '='
str = ['', *words].join(j)
re = "[^#{j}]*"

str =~ /\A
    (?: #{j} ( #{re} ) #{re} )
    (?: #{j}    \1     #{re} )*
\z/x

p $1
```

**And the one-liner, courtesy of mislav (50 characters):**

```
p ARGV.join(' ').match(/^(\w*)\w*(?: \1\w*)*$/)[1]
```

Comment: Nice! A one-line version of this would be `words.join(" ").match(/^(\w*)\w*(?: \1\w*)*$/)[1]`. Note: the regexp would have to be updated slightly to make this work when matching strings that have spaces in them.

Answer (score 4):

In Python I wouldn't use anything but the existing `commonprefix` function I showed in another answer, but I couldn't help to reinvent the wheel `:P`. This is my iterator-based approach:

```
>>> a = 'interspecies interstelar interstate'.split()
>>>
>>> from itertools import takewhile, chain, izip as zip, imap as map
>>> ''.join(chain(*takewhile(lambda s: len(s) == 1, map(set, zip(*a)))))
'inters'
```

**Edit:** Explanation of how this works.

`zip` generates tuples of elements taking one of each item of `a` at a time:

```
In [6]: list(zip(*a))  # here I use list() to expand the iterator
Out[6]:
[('i', 'i', 'i'),
 ('n', 'n', 'n'),
 ('t', 't', 't'),
 ('e', 'e', 'e'),
 ('r', 'r', 'r'),
 ('s', 's', 's'),
 ('p', 't', 't'),
 ('e', 'e', 'a'),
 ('c', 'l', 't'),
 ('i', 'a', 'e')]
```

By mapping `set` over these items, I get a series of unique letters:

```
In [7]: list(map(set, _))  # _ means the result of the last statement above
Out[7]:
[set(['i']),
 set(['n']),
 set(['t']),
 set(['e']),
 set(['r']),
 set(['s']),
 set(['p', 't']),
 set(['a', 'e']),
 set(['c', 'l', 't']),
 set(['a', 'e', 'i'])]
```

`takewhile(predicate, items)` takes elements from this while the predicate is True; in this particular case, when the `set`s have one element, i.e. all the words have the same letter at that position:

```
In [8]: list(takewhile(lambda s: len(s) == 1, _))
Out[8]:
[set(['i']),
 set(['n']), 
 set(['t']), 
 set(['e']), 
 set(['r']), 
 set(['s'])]
```

At this point we have an iterable of sets, each containing one letter of the prefix we were looking for. To construct the string, we `chain` them into a single iterable, from which we get the letters to `join` into the final string.

The magic of using iterators is that all items are generated on demand, so when `takewhile` stops asking for items, the zipping stops at that point and no unnecessary work is done. Each function call in my one-liner has a implicit `for` and an implicit `break`.

Comment: Could you decompose the solution and elaborate a bit on iterators used?

Comment: why "izip" and "imap"? at first thought it could be that they are case-insensitive, but then I realized that doesn't make much sense

Comment: `izip` and `imap` return iterators, while `zip` and `map` return lists. By using lists, all tuples are generated, even though `takewhile` will never see most of them. In Python 3 `zip` and `map` return iterators, so it's not necessary to import them from `itertools`.

Comment: It reminds me of Haskell. Really functional style python code.

Comment: Learning Haskell has certainly affected my Python :)

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not the most concise solution (depends if you already have a library for this), but one elegant method is to use a trie. I use tries for implementing tab completion in my Scheme interpreter:

http://github.com/jcoglan/heist/blob/master/lib/trie.rb

For example:

```
tree = Trie.new
%w[interspecies interstelar interstate].each { |s| tree[s] = true }
tree.longest_prefix('')
#=> "inters"
```

I also use them for matching channel names with wildcards for the Bayeux protocol; see these:

http://github.com/jcoglan/faye/blob/master/client/channel.js

http://github.com/jcoglan/faye/blob/master/lib/faye/channel.rb

Comment: You don't need a trie.  As soon as any branch would occur, you're done anyway.

Comment: Really interesting—thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

Just for the fun of it, here's a version written in (SWI-)PROLOG:

```
common_pre([[C|Cs]|Ss], [C|Res]) :-
  maplist(head_tail(C), [[C|Cs]|Ss], RemSs), !,
  common_pre(RemSs, Res).
common_pre(_, []).

head_tail(H, [H|T], T).
```

Running:

```
?- S=["interspecies", "interstelar", "interstate"], common_pre(S, CP), string_to_list(CPString, CP).
```

Gives:

```
CP = [105, 110, 116, 101, 114, 115],
CPString = "inters".
```

Explanation:

(SWI-)PROLOG treats strings as lists of character codes (numbers). All the predicate `common_pre/2` does is recursively pattern-match to select the first code (`C`) from the head of the first list (string, `[C|Cs]`) in the list of all lists (all strings, `[[C|Cs]|Ss]`), and appends the matching code `C` to the result *iff* it is common to all (remaining) heads of all lists (strings), else it terminates.

Nice, clean, simple and efficient... :)

Answer (score 3):

A javascript version based on [@Svante's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916218/find-the-longest-common-starting-substring-in-a-set-of-strings/1916492#1916492):

```
function commonSubstring(words){
    var iChar, iWord,
        refWord = words[0],
        lRefWord = refWord.length,
        lWords = words.length;
    for (iChar = 0; iChar < lRefWord; iChar += 1) {
        for (iWord = 1; iWord < lWords; iWord += 1) {
            if (refWord[iChar] !== words[iWord][iChar]) {
                return refWord.substring(0, iChar);
            }
        }
    }
    return refWord;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Combining answers by **kennebec**, **Florian F** and **jberryman** yields the following Haskell one-liner:

```
commonPrefix l = map fst . takeWhile (uncurry (==)) $ zip (minimum l) (maximum l)
```

With `Control.Arrow` one can get a point-free form:

```
commonPrefix = map fst . takeWhile (uncurry (==)) . uncurry zip . (minimum &&& maximum)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Python 2.6 (r26:66714, Oct  4 2008, 02:48:43) 

>>> a = ['interspecies', 'interstelar', 'interstate']

>>> print a[0][:max(
        [i for i in range(min(map(len, a))) 
            if len(set(map(lambda e: e[i], a))) == 1]
        ) + 1]

inters
```

- `i for i in range(min(map(len, a)))`, number of maximum lookups can't be greater than the length of the shortest string; in this example this would evaluate to `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`
- `len(set(map(lambda e: e[i], a)))`, 1) create an array of the `i-th`character for each string in the list; 2) make a set out of it; 3) determine the size of the set
- `[i for i in range(min(map(len, a))) if len(set(map(lambda e: e[i], a))) == 1]`, include just the characters, for which the size of the set is 1 (all characters at that position were the same ..); here it would evaluate to `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
- finally take the `max`, add one, and get the substring ...

Note: the above does not work for `a = ['intersyate', 'intersxate', 'interstate', 'intersrate']`, but this would:

```
 >>> index = len(
         filter(lambda l: l[0] == l[1], 
             [ x for x in enumerate(
                 [i for i in range(min(map(len, a))) 
                     if len(set(map(lambda e: e[i], a))) == 1]
         )]))
 >>> a[0][:index]
 inters
```

Comment: Neat. Checking the sizes of vertical sets is smart

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't seem that complicated if you're not too concerned about ultimate performance:

```
def common_substring(data)
  data.inject { |m, s| s[0,(0..m.length).find { |i| m[i] != s[i] }.to_i] }
end
```

One of the useful features of inject is the ability to pre-seed with the first element of the array being interated over. This avoids the nil memo check.

```
puts common_substring(%w[ interspecies interstelar interstate ]).inspect
# => "inters"
puts common_substring(%w[ feet feel feeble ]).inspect
# => "fee"
puts common_substring(%w[ fine firkin fail ]).inspect
# => "f"
puts common_substring(%w[ alpha bravo charlie ]).inspect
# => ""
puts common_substring(%w[ fork ]).inspect
# => "fork"
puts common_substring(%w[ fork forks ]).inspect
# => "fork"
```

*Update:* If golf is the game here, then 67 characters:

```
def f(d)d.inject{|m,s|s[0,(0..m.size).find{|i|m[i]!=s[i]}.to_i]}end
```

Comment: No, this isn't golf. I actually had to look the phrase up to know what it means :) By "elegant code" I meant code that is readable, understandable and clever. Removing whitespace and shortening method/variable names is opposite from readable and understandable, and does not make the solution any more clever.

Thanks for the `inject` tip! Wasn't aware of that.

Comment: I know what you're saying about golfing, but couldn't let Jordan's effort go unchallenged.

Answer (score 2):

This one is very similar to Roberto Bonvallet's solution, except in ruby.

```
chars = %w[interspecies interstelar interstate].map {|w| w.split('') }
chars[0].zip(*chars[1..-1]).map { |c| c.uniq }.take_while { |c| c.size == 1 }.join
```

The first line replaces each word with an array of chars. Next, I use `zip` to create this data structure:

`[["i", "i", "i"], ["n", "n", "n"], ["t", "t", "t"], ...`

`map` and `uniq` reduce this to `[["i"],["n"],["t"], ...`

`take_while` pulls the chars off the array until it finds one where the size isn't one (meaning not all chars were the same). Finally, I `join` them back together.

Comment: Didn't know ruby had a take_while—thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916218/find-the-longest-common-starting-substring-in-a-set-of-strings#1917041) is broken (for example, it returns `a` for strings like `['a', 'ba']`). The fix is very simple, you literally have to change only 3 characters (from `indexOf(tem1) == -1` to `indexOf(tem1) != 0`) and the function would work as expected.

Unfortunately, when I tried to edit the answer to fix the typo, SO told me that "edits must be at least 6 characters". I *could* change more then those 3 chars, by improving naming and readability but that feels like a little bit too much.

So, below is a fixed and improved (at least from my point of view) version of the kennebec's solution:

```js
function commonPrefix(words) {
  max_word = words.reduce(function(a, b) { return a > b ? a : b });
  prefix   = words.reduce(function(a, b) { return a > b ? b : a }); // min word

  while(max_word.indexOf(prefix) != 0) {
    prefix = prefix.slice(0, -1);
  }

  return prefix;
}
```

(on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexisowl/ZUAG7/))

Note, that it uses [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method (JavaScript 1.8) in order to find alphanumeric max / min instead of sorting the array and then fetching the first and the last elements of it.

Answer (score 2):

While reading these answers with all the fancy functional programming, sorting and regexes and whatnot, I just thought: what's wrong a little bit of C? So here's a goofy looking little program.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i = -1, j, c;

  if (argc < 2)
    return 1;

  while (c = argv[1][++i])
    for (j = 2; j < argc; j++)
      if (argv[j][i] != c)
        goto out;

 out:
  printf("Longest common prefix: %.*s\n", i, argv[1]);
}
```

Compile it, run it with your list of strings as command line arguments, then upvote me for using `goto`!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using regular expressions in Ruby:

```
def build_regex(string)
  arr = []
  arr << string.dup while string.chop!
  Regexp.new("^(#{arr.join("|")})")
end

def substring(first, *strings)
  strings.inject(first) do |accum, string|
    build_regex(accum).match(string)[0]
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm interested in how it performs. I can't make up my mind if it would be faster or slower than the reference solution(s). But I know you're already writing benchmarks ;) *waits patiently*

Comment: You don't need regular expressions, because all you need is linear string comparison.  This implementation is particularly inefficient because you build a new regex in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

1. Take the first string of the array as the initial *starting substring*.
2. Take the next string of the array and compare the characters until the end of one of the strings is reached or a mismatch is found. If a mismatch is found, reduce *starting substring* to the length where the mismatch was found.
3. Repeat step 2 until all strings have been tested.

Here’s a JavaScript implementation:

```
var array = ["interspecies", "interstelar", "interstate"],
    prefix = array[0],
    len = prefix.length;
for (i=1; i<array.length; i++) {
    for (j=0, len=Math.min(len,array[j].length); j<len; j++) {
        if (prefix[j] != array[i][j]) {
            len = j;
            prefix = prefix.substr(0, len);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is inefficient because you likely make comparisons that are superfluous when a later string further shortens the result.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sorting, you could just get the min and max of the strings.

To me, elegance in a computer program is a balance of speed and simplicity.
It should not do unnecessary computation, and it should be simple enough to make its correctness evident.

I could call the sorting solution "clever", but not "elegant".

Answer (score 1):

Oftentimes it's more elegant to use a mature open source library instead of rolling your own. Then, if it doesn't completely suit your needs, you can extend it or modify it to improve it, and let the community decide if that belongs in the library.

[diff-lcs](http://rubygems.org/gems/diff-lcs) is a good Ruby gem for least common substring.

Answer (score 1):

My solution in Java:

```
public static String compute(Collection<String> strings) {
    if(strings.isEmpty()) return "";
    Set<Character> v = new HashSet<Character>();
    int i = 0;
    try {
        while(true) {
            for(String s : strings) v.add(s.charAt(i));
            if(v.size() > 1) break;
            v.clear();
            i++;
        }
    } catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {}
    return strings.iterator().next().substring(0, i);
}
```

Comment: Not Unicode-safe. :p

Answer (score 1):

Golfed JS solution just for fun:

```
w=["hello", "hell", "helen"];
c=w.reduce(function(p,c){
    for(r="",i=0;p[i]==c[i];r+=p[i],i++){}
    return r;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an efficient solution in ruby. I based the idea of the strategy for a hi/lo guessing game where you iteratively zero in on the longest prefix.

Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the complexity is O(n log n), where n is the length of the shortest string and the number of strings is considered a constant.

```
def common(strings)
  lo = 0
  hi = strings.map(&:length).min - 1
  return '' if hi < lo

  guess, last_guess = lo, hi

  while guess != last_guess
    last_guess = guess
    guess = lo + ((hi - lo) / 2.0).ceil

    if strings.map { |s| s[0..guess] }.uniq.length == 1
      lo = guess
    else
      hi = guess
    end
  end

  strings.map { |s| s[0...guess] }.uniq.length == 1 ? strings.first[0...guess] : ''
end
```

And some checks that it works:

```
>> common %w{ interspecies interstelar interstate }
=> "inters"

>> common %w{ dog dalmation }
=> "d"

>> common %w{ asdf qwerty }
=> ""

>> common ['', 'asdf']
=> ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Fun alternative Ruby solution:

```
def common_prefix(*strings)
  chars  = strings.map(&:chars)
  length = chars.first.zip( *chars[1..-1] ).index{ |a| a.uniq.length>1 }
  strings.first[0,length]
end

p common_prefix( 'foon', 'foost', 'forlorn' ) #=> "fo"
p common_prefix( 'foost', 'foobar', 'foon'  ) #=> "foo"
p common_prefix( 'a','b'  )                   #=> ""
```

It might help speed if you used `chars = strings.sort_by(&:length).map(&:chars)`, since the shorter the first string, the shorter the arrays created by `zip`. However, if you cared about speed, you probably shouldn't use this solution anyhow. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means elegant, but if you want concise:

### Ruby, 71 chars

```
def f(a)b=a[0];b[0,(0..b.size).find{|n|a.any?{|i|i[0,n]!=b[0,n]}}-1]end
```

If you want that unrolled it looks like this:

```
def f(words)
  first_word = words[0];
  first_word[0, (0..(first_word.size)).find { |num_chars|
    words.any? { |word| word[0, num_chars] != first_word[0, num_chars] }
  } - 1]
end
```

Comment: Apparently this doesn't work on single-element arrays, but otherwise is pretty compact.

Comment: Add the line `return first_word if words.length==1` as the second line of the function and it should handle single-element arrays as well.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript clone of [AShelly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916218/find-the-longest-common-starting-substring-in-a-set-of-strings/1916480#1916480)'s excellent answer.

Requires `Array#reduce` which is supported only in firefox.

```
var strings = ["interspecies", "intermediate", "interrogation"]
var sub = strings.reduce(function(l,r) { 
    while(l!=r.slice(0,l.length)) {  
        l = l.slice(0, -1);
    }
    return l;
});
```

Comment: This traverses each string once for every character not in the result; e.g., a string that is the result plus 10 characters gets traversed 10 times.  This is not very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It's not code golf, but you asked for somewhat elegant, and I tend to think recursion is fun.  Java.

```
/** Recursively find the common prefix. */
public String findCommonPrefix(String[] strings) {

    int minLength = findMinLength(strings);

    if (isFirstCharacterSame(strings)) {
        return strings[0].charAt(0) + findCommonPrefix(removeFirstCharacter(strings));
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

/** Get the minimum length of a string in strings[]. */
private int findMinLength(final String[] strings) {
    int length = strings[0].size();
    for (String string : strings) {
        if (string.size() < length) {
            length = string.size();
        }
    }
    return length;
}

/** Compare the first character of all strings. */
private boolean isFirstCharacterSame(String[] strings) {
    char c = string[0].charAt(0);
    for (String string : strings) {
        if (c != string.charAt(0)) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

/** Remove the first character of each string in the array, 
    and return a new array with the results. */
private String[] removeFirstCharacter(String[] source) {
    String[] result = new String[source.length];
    for (int i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = source[i].substring(1); 
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I will not condemn recursion, but you are building a new string for concatenating each character of the result.  Otherwise, the approach is ok.

Answer (score 0):

A ruby version based on @Svante's algorithm.   Runs ~3x as fast as my first one.

```
 def common_prefix set 
   i=0
   rest=set[1..-1]
   set[0].each_byte{|c|
     rest.each{|e|return set[0][0...i] if e[i]!=c}
     i+=1
   }
   set
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

My **Javascript** solution:

IMOP, using sort is too tricky.
My solution is compare letter by letter through looping the array.
Return string if letter is not macthed.

This is my solution:

```
var longestCommonPrefix = function(strs){
    if(strs.length < 1){
        return '';
    }

    var p = 0, i = 0, c = strs[0][0];

    while(p < strs[i].length && strs[i][p] === c){
        i++;
        if(i === strs.length){
            i = 0;
            p++;
            c = strs[0][p];
        }
    }

    return strs[0].substr(0, p);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Realizing the risk of this turning into a match of [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) (or is that the intention?), here's my solution using `sed`, copied from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17475354/588561) to another SO question and shortened to 36 chars (30 of which are the actual `sed` expression). It expects the strings (each on a seperate line) to be supplied on standard input or in files passed as additional arguments.

```
sed 'N;s/^\(.*\).*\n\1.*$/\1\n\1/;D'
```

A script with sed in the shebang line weighs in at 45 chars:

```
#!/bin/sed -f
N;s/^\(.*\).*\n\1.*$/\1\n\1/;D
```

A test run of the script (named `longestprefix`), with strings supplied as a "here document":

```
$ ./longestprefix <<EOF
> interspecies
> interstelar
> interstate
> EOF
inters
$
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ruby**

```
require 'abbrev'

ar = ["interspecies", "interstelar", "interstate"]
ar.abbrev.keys.min_by(&:size).chop # => "inters"
```

Given a set of strings,`abbrev` calculates the set of unambiguous abbreviations for those strings, and return a hash where the keys are all the possible abbreviations (and the values are the full strings).The shortest key minus the last char will be the common prefix.