# Grouping elements of a character vector by the first n letters that match each other

Tags: r, pattern-matching

Goal: I want to find a way to group a character vector like:

```
x <- c("a800k blue 5", "a800j", "bb-blah5", "a800 7", "bb-blah2", "bb-blah3")
```

into groups with sort of "lead matches" that give the minimum elements so that they would be called in a `grep` search. So the solution to the toy example above would be:

```
solution <- c("a800", "bb-blah")
```

because a `grep` search of x using the pattern "a800" would yield all 3 elements that start with "a800."

Note: I can make very few assumptions about the character strings that will be contained in the vector. There will be lengths varying between just a few and quite long strings (possibly 10 or more), containing combinations of numbers, letters, spaces, and some special characters that make life very difficult.

So I would love a function that works something like `intersect`, maybe, but on each individual string.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps you find something useful here, at least to get you started: [Find common substrings between two character variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196327/find-common-substrings-between-two-character-variables), [longest common substring in R finding non-contiguous matches between the two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261825/longest-common-substring-in-r-finding-non-contiguous-matches-between-the-two-str)

Comment: [R implementation for Finding the longest common starting substrings in a set of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273716/r-implementation-for-finding-the-longest-common-starting-substrings-in-a-set-of)

Answer (score 0):

There may be more elegant (efficient) ways, but this works on your sample strings. The longest common prefix is calculated (`Biobase::lcPrefixC`*) on pairwise combinations (`combn`) of strings.

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("Biobase")

unique(combn(seq_along(x), 2, FUN = function(cm) lcPrefixC(x[cm])))
# [1] "a800"    ""        "bb-blah"
```

---

It's unclear if you are trading between length of prefix and size of groups. For example:

```
x <- c("1234", "1235", "1245", "1246")
```

Would you rather have one larger group with a shorter prefix (`"12"`), or two smaller groups with with longer prefix (`"123"` and `"124"`)?

---

*"`lcPrefixC` is a faster implementation in C. [But note that] It only handles ascii characters". See also `lcPrefix`.

---

Comment: I should mention that I'm under the constraint of using R 3.2.0, and cannot use most packages written since. Ideally, I would use base R.

Comment: OK, I see! So you didn't manage to run the code I proposed at all? Cheers.