# Find the Longest Common starting substring of S2 in S1

Tags: c++, regex, string, data-structures

I was solving a problem. i solved the Longest Common starting substring of S2 in S1 part but the time complexity was very high.

In the below Code I have to find the Longest Common starting substring of str3 in s[i].
In the below code instead of find function i have also use KMP algorithm but i faced high time complexity again.

```
 string str3=abstring1(c,1,2,3);
                while(1)
                {
                    size_t found = s[i].find(str3);
                    if(str3.length()==0)
                        break;
                    if (found != string::npos)
                    {
                        str1=str1+str3;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        str3.pop_back();
                    }
                }
```

**Example : 

S1=balling    S2=baller 

ans=ball 

S1=balling    S2=uolling

ans=**



We have to **find common starting substring of S2 in S1**
Can you help in c++
I find [Similar Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916218/find-the-longest-common-starting-substring-in-a-set-of-strings) but i was not able to do my self in c++.

Comment: Why is the answer to your second example not `"lling"`?

Comment: Because it's mandatory to consider starting of S2 starting letters are uo

Comment: @CarySwoveland you can also check the similar post .. i have mentioned the link in last

Comment: Ah, *starting* substring. That's simplifies the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that emits the faint aroma of a hack.

Suppose

```
s1 = 'snowballing'
s2 = 'baller'
```

Then form the string

```
s = s2 + '|' + s1
  #=> 'baller|snowballing'
```

where the pipe (`'|'`) can be any character that is not in either string. (If in doubt, one could use, say, `"\x00"`.)

We may then match `s` against the regular expression

```
^(.*)(?=.*\|.*\1)
```

This will match the longest starting string in `s2` that is present in `s1`, which in this example is `'ball'`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YW8RoY/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^        # match beginning of string
(        # begin capture group 1
  .*     # match zero or more characters, as many as possible
)        # end capture group 1
(?=      # begin a positive lookahead
  .*     # match zero or more characters, as many as possible 
  \|     # match '|'
  .*     # match zero or more characters, as many as possible 
  \1     # match the contents of capture group 1
)        # end positive lookahead
```

Comment: This is what I want. But can you help me doing the same thing for c++

Comment: Sorry, but I don't speak C++. Perhaps a reader can help. The C++ code should be short and sweet.