# List wildcard tables bigquery schema

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, wildcard

I want to **list the tables** which can be used as **wildcards** in BigQuery.

My **dataset** has the table list is similar to the following:

```
events_122022
events_122021
events_122020
...
...
events_112012
...
...

analytics_122022
analytics_122021
analytics_122020
...
...
analytics_112012
```

These tables are created dynamically and I have no information on the used table prefix
Is there a way to find the list of tables which can be used dynamically?

The result should be:**`[events_, analytics_]`**

#### My attempt:

Find the **tables with similar DDL** using the following SQL

```
   SELECT
    SUBSTR(ddl, STRPOS(ddl, '(')) as commonDDL,
    STRING_AGG(table_name) as table
  FROM
    dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  GROUP BY SUBSTR(ddl, STRPOS(ddl, '('))
```

This gives the **output** as :

| commonDDL | table |
| --- | --- |
| (ID STRING, ...) | events_122022, events_122021, ... |
| (NAME STRING, ...) | analytics_112022, analytics_112021 ... |

Now using a Longest common shared start algorithm I can find the required result.
(Longest common start code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916218/find-the-longest-common-starting-substring-in-a-set-of-strings/1917041#1917041) )

What are the **other ways we can approach this problem**?

Couldn't find anything on BigQuery docs.

*Note: I only have readonly permission for the BigQuery dataset*

Answer (score 0):

What about finding your table with some regex:

```
select table_name
from yourds.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where regexp_contains(table_name, "_[0-2]+") is true
```

Comment: Won't this just return the table names as `events_122022 , events_112012 , events_112013` . I wanted to find the tables as `[events_, analytics_]`.

Comment: Oh. I didn't get that you wanted the result to be in an array. Have a look at this an let me know how you go? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#constructing_arrays